# how to develop a website as an extension

Tags: typo3

i have a question for TYPO3 version 7:
when devloping a website with the fluidtypo3 (fluidcontent, fluidpages) extensions it is a need to develop the website as an extension , called provider extension.

In this extension i save all the necessary stuff like templates, typoscript configuration and css and so on.

But how can i save my site as an extension if i do not use fluidtypo3. Actual i only use mask and gridelements.

Does there exist a tutorial?

best regards
Markus

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @lexi typo3 has a fairly steep access curve, in the beginning its even hard to formulate what your actual questions are, I retain that a 'basic orientation question' for typo3 does not indicate that the person was not willing to research enough ...

Comment: @webMan I'm just copying what the full flag is. Never said they weren't researching enough. The fact of the matter is, the heart of this question is asking for a tutorial recommendation and that isn't really what SO has been meant for.

Comment: @lexi I think you are right ... i think too though that for typo3 some slack should be given, its really hard to find out how to set the first steps, I'm sure there are a number of people that are going to look at this question because they are curious how to go about ...

Comment: @markus-dübbert did you check it out ?

Answer (score 0):

I know a **basic** tutorial for v6.2 which is still pretty pertinent: (I hope you speak german)

Tutorial: TYPO3 6.2 - Die Distribution -> [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VAoaog8TAo)

Tutorial: TYPO3 6.2 - Das Template -> [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rclwzW4gx1c)

Tutorial: TYPO3 6.2 - Das Menu -> [yoututbe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEFv8kJuHME)

you start from there so that you have your basic structure and to setup everything you want to change from the originals of the various other extensions you will use ...

You would also activate an extension like gridelements to have the content elements and structure at your disposal ... I like to work with [EXT:t3sbootstrap](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/t3sbootstrap) which gives you a very quick way to create your site ... (it works with gridelements and has a very nice [documentation](http://www.t3sbootstrap.de/)) **BUT** you always start with your own extension (called distribution) like panadeedu explains on youtube ...

*(best practice is not to touch extensions otherwise updates becomes very hard, with typo3 you can simply overwrite the exact same variables and objects in your extension by placing them after the originals in the static templates include)*

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed a empty Typo3 you could try this, i wrote that for exact that problem:

https://github.com/misterboe/startpilot

If you have any questions, just contact me on typo3 slack (@mrboe)

It contains examples for:

- Backend Layout
- Frontend Tempalte
- Content Elements